Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed after applying make.unique ()
I need to make 4 different matrices using the same data frame before running a LassoGLMM with the code I have. It is a large microbiome data set. I created my first matrix with no issues. However, when I try to make the next matrix R tells me duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed.
Here is a sample of my data 'Lasdf'
head(Lasdf)
           Sample Abundance    Individual GIT Sex AgeClass Total_Dose_CaptureGh
1 WB20190205_01JE   0.92150 WB20190205_O1  JE   F    Adult            4.9035521
2 WB20190205_01DU   0.83575 WB20190205_O1  DU   F    Adult            4.9035521
3  WB20190221_1JE   0.75350 WB20190221_C1  JE   M Subadult            0.2390906
4 WB20190130_01JE   0.73975 WB20190130_O1  JE   F    Adult            2.3538941
5  WB20190128_2DU   0.73575  WB20190128_2  DU   M    Adult            0.2145515
6  WB20190217_2JE   0.70800 WB20190217_C2  JE   F Yearling            0.2980213
                        Genus                      SampleID
1               Lactobacillus WB20190205_01JE_WB20190205_O1
2               Lactobacillus WB20190205_01DU_WB20190205_O1
3               Lactobacillus  WB20190221_1JE_WB20190221_C1
4 Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1 WB20190130_01JE_WB20190130_O1
5   Family_Enterobacteriaceae   WB20190128_2DU_WB20190128_2
6               Lactobacillus  WB20190217_2JE_WB20190217_C2

I created my first matrix with no issues using the code below:
## Data should be in the following formats:
# tMBdat: 16S/ITS relative abundance data in 1 matrix, samples in rows and OTUs/species in columns with identifiable names
MBdat<- create.matrix(Lasdf, tax.name = "Genus",
                    locality = "SampleID",
                    abund.col = "Abundance",
                    abund = TRUE)
#Transpose it using the function t(df) to change Genus to the columns and Sample to the rows.
`tMBdat<-t(MBdat)`

Sample output:
WB20190114_1_DU_WB20190114_1  0.00925     0.00000      0.00000
WB20190114_2_JE_WB20190114_1  0.00150     0.00050      0.00050
WB20190114_3_IL_WB20190114_1  0.00125     0.00050      0.00200
WB20190114_4_CE_WB20190114_1  0.00125     0.00000      0.00000
WB20190114_5_CO_WB20190114_1  0.00100     0.00325      0.00000
WB20190114_6_DC_WB20190114_1  0.00075     0.00050      0.00250

When I try to make the next matrix with the code:
# dat: continuous response variables in 1 matrix, samples in rows, and variables in columns with identifiable names
dat<- subset(Lasdf, select = c(SampleID, Total_Dose_CaptureGh))
dat %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var="SampleID")

dat is created.
head(dat)
                      SampleID Total_Dose_CaptureGh
1 WB20190205_01JE_WB20190205_O1            4.9035521
2 WB20190205_01DU_WB20190205_O1            4.9035521
3  WB20190221_1JE_WB20190221_C1            0.2390906
4 WB20190130_01JE_WB20190130_O1            2.3538941
5   WB20190128_2DU_WB20190128_2            0.2145515
6  WB20190217_2JE_WB20190217_C2            0.2980213

However, I get the following error when I try to use "SampleID" as row names even though the row names are now unique:
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘WB20190114_1_DU_WB20190114_1’, ‘WB20190114_2_JE_WB20190114_1’, ‘WB20190114_3_IL_WB20190114_1’, ‘WB20190114_4_CE_WB20190114_1’, ‘WB20190114_5_CO_WB20190114_1’, [... truncated] 

I am not sure how to proceed.

What packages are you using? In particular, what package is create.matrix() from?

I will go back and edit the tables. They did not look like that in the preview. I am still new.

create.matrix() is from fossil: Palaeoecological and Palaeogeographical Analysis Tools

Hmm okay, so I do still have duplicate names. > length(unique(dat$SampleID)) == nrow(dat)
[1] FALSE I will work on figuring out which ones are not unique. Any ideas how to fix that if
#Make SampleID names unique before transforming into different matrices
make.unique(as.character(Lasdf$SampleID), sep = "_")
did not work?

dput() is not helpful as the data set is huge. I cannot even see the start of the output but here is a sample 1.6145279, 2.35389412, 9.00749508, 0.14024659, 2.3698745, 0.25337071,
0.297657013, 0.315387624, 2.35389412, 0.23909062, 2.94574399,
0.187469584, 2.3464, 0.42320039, 0.137758161, 0.2, 3.34736686,
0.14659349, 0.10377349, 1.6145279, 0.14024659, 0.25337071, 0.1752552,
0.25337071, 2.35389412, 5.338442202, 0.1752552, 0.297657013,
3.34736686, 0.187469584, 0.298021325, 0.298021325, 3.11761085,
0.42320039, 0.137758161, 2.3464, 1.6145279, 3.0085184, 0.14659349,

dplyr::distinct(Lasdf, SampleID, .keep_all=TRUE)

dplyr::distinct(Lasdf, SampleID, .keep_all=TRUE)
It appears to work but then:

length(unique(Lasdf$SampleID)) == nrow(Lasdf)
[1] FALSE
And
dat<- subset(Lasdf, select = c(SampleID, Total_Dose_CaptureGh))
remove_rownames(dat)
column_to_rownames(dat, var="SampleID")
Error in .rowNamesDF<-(x, value = value) :
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘


So I tried just creating a matrix and using SampleID as row names but it creates the matrix but will not use SampleID as rownames

mdat<- as.matrix(dat, rownames= TRUE, rownames.value= "SampleID")#does not work
head(mdat)
SampleID                        Total_Dose_CaptureGh
1 "WB20190205_01JE_WB20190205_O1" " 4.9035521"
2 "WB20190205_01DU_WB20190205_O1" " 4.9035521"
3 "WB20190221_1JE_WB20190221_C1"  " 0.2390906"


Thank you zephryl for editing my question. I figured it out. The code below worked

Lasdf$SampleID <- sub('[ . ]', '_', make.names(Lasdf$SampleID, unique=TRUE))
